# No Neutron in Openstack

Tags: networking, conjure-up

No ability to see "Network" in the OpenStack dashboard.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
On last screenshot, Devstack is on the left, Ubuntu/Openstack/Conjure-up is on the right.  Devstack there for comparison only.

[image: juju status]

[image: lxc list]

[image: Devstack on the left, Ubuntu/OS/Conjure-up on the right]

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure by now you have removed this deployment so I will answer for benefit of other people who come across anything similar. You could try to see what went wrong with:

```
juju debug-log --replay
```

And see why this specific machine had problems. Also, it seems that it doesn't have an IP address, Maybe take a look inside the container -in this instance, it would be  `lxc exec juju-59a369-11 bash` and see if there is anything in the logs of the container. Start with `ip a` to check for address.

To resolve I would run

```
juju add-unit neutron-api
```

This will deploy another machine (lxc) and unit of neutron-api called neutron-api/1 and add all required relationships.
Afterwards its a case of

```
juju remove-unit neutron-api/0
```

to clean up.

Hope this will help.
B