# Testing openstack with conjure-up (novalxc) neutron-gateway fails to start

Tags: juju, openstack, lxd, conjure-up, nova

Followed this doc to test openstack: https://www.ubuntu.com/openstack/install#workstation-deployment

edit: This is running on ubuntu 16.04

After the conjure-up step, everything eventually starts fine except for neutron-gateway. It is stuck at "waiting for machine." I've tried this on a physical server with 20 physical cores (40 threads), 96GB RAM, and over 200GB of available disk space. So I don't think it is a resource issue. (I've also tried on a VM with 8 cores and 64 GB RAM and got the same result.) I've tried both the stable and edge releases of conjure-up.

Here is lxc list (juju-7e83fd-12 is neutron-gateway):

[image]

Here is lxc info --show-log:

[image]

I can still get to the openstack dashboard. But under Project | Network | Networks there are no networks configured. Since this is my first time trying openstack, I don't know if that is expected or if it is a symptom of this issue. Any ideas on how to get past this?

Comment: Can you please show output of

    `juju status`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I already answered something similar here:
[No Neutron in Openstack](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088908/no-neutron-in-openstack/1096597#1096597)

And based on your comment "there are no networks configured" I feel that we missing neutron-api. Hence I asked to provide `juju status` so we can see which unit didn't deploy correctly.

So to resolve, You could try to see what went wrong with:

```
juju debug-log --replay
```

And see why this specific machine had problems. From your output it seems that ipv4 address is missing. Would be good to understand if there is anything on the network that provides ipv6 - if it is - disable it or if you can not disable just ipv6, spin up lxc container and add dnsmasq to manage DHCP for you. 
I would take a look inside the container - in this instance, it would be `lxc exec juju-7e83fd-12 bash` and see if there is anything in the logs of the container. Start with `ip a` to check for address.

To resolve I would run

```
juju add-unit neutron-api
```

This will deploy another machine (lxc) and unit of neutron-api called neutron-api/1 and add all required relationships. Afterwards its a case of

```
juju remove-unit neutron-api/0
```

to clean up.

Hope this will help. B

Comment: Thanks for this reply! Unfortunately I blew it away and re-did it but without conjure-up. So I can't gather more information and troubleshoot any further. I ended up going with this procedure instead - https://docs.openstack.org/charm-guide/latest/openstack-on-lxd.html. I had much more luck doing it this way.

Comment: No worries :) and the link in your comment is also good.